# Searching some characters in text gives no results

Tags: windows-7, notepad++, characters

I have this problem within many programs but to isolate the problem, I do this:
I have `myfile.cpp` file. This file has this method:

```
findmyIds() {
...
}
```

I open Notepad++ or Visual Studio or other text editor. I search for `findmyIds` word, I get no results. When I search `findmyids` editor finds the method. The file is UTF8 encoded. I use Windows 7 Ultimate with Turkish language pack.

From Control Panel >> Regional and Language Options >>

- Keyboards and other languages >> I added Turkish keyboard. Changed display language to Turkish
- Administrative >> I changed current locale to Turkish

But still same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you're searching in the right direction, and/or that `Wrap around` is checked in the find dialogue. I've tested it now and both `findmyids` and `findmyIds` will return a result provided you're wrap searching or searching upwards/downwards with the intended result in the right direction.